# Plot[ D[Sin[x]] ] and Evaluate[]

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

Why does

```
t = 2 Pi;
Plot[D[Sin[x],x], {x,0,t}] (* Plotting the derivative of Sin[x] *)
```

not work, but

```
t = 2 Pi;
Plot[Evaluate[D[Sin[x],x], {x,0,t}] (* Plotting the evaluation of the derivative of Sin[x]? *)
```

do? And why does this work, but neither

```
t = 2 Pi;
Plot[{D[Sin[x],x]}, {x,0,t}] (* Plotting the one-length array of the derivative of Sin[x] *)
```

nor

```
t = 2 Pi;
Plot[{Evaluate[D[Sin[x],x]]}, {x,0,t}] (* Plotting the one-length array of the evaluation of the derivative of Sin[x]? *)
```

works?

Comment: umm, none of these work unless you define `t`, but to answer the question, it is because one of the attributes of the `Plot` function is `HoldAll`. The [relevant documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) has an example with `Plot` that explains in more detail

Comment: I added the constant t. I still don't quite understand, though. In the first example, I have an evaluated function, and Plot needs an evaluated one. In the fourth example I should have the same thing, but inside an array.

Comment: In the first example you *don't* have an evaluated function. That's precisely the point. The derivative is held by Plot and then values for x are filled in. You then have a derivative with respect to a number which is nonsense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I always picture it like this: `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll`, so it gets the unevaluated expression `D[Sin[x],x]`. Then it replaces all occurrences of `x` with `5` and evaluates the result. So it tries to evaluate something like `D[Sin[5],5]`. Which is of course nonsensical, because you can't derive by a constant.

If you call `Plot[Evaluate[D[Sin[x],x], ...`, the expression gets evaluated before it's passed to `Plot`. So it's equivalent to `Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, t}]`. Now if `Plot` replaces `x` by `5`, it gets a nice real number it can plot.

However, this only happens when `Evaluate` is the head of the expression passed to `Plot`. If you pass something like `x+5/(Evaluate[y])`, the subexpression `y` isn't evaluated. `HoldAll` doesn't "look inside" the expression, to see if there's an `Evaluate` nested somewhere. That's why `Plot[{Evaluate[D[Sin[x],x]]}, ...` doesn't work.

However, `Plot[Evaluate[{D[Sin[x], x]}], {x, 0, t}]` does work, because `Evaluate` is the head of the expression

Comment: But oddly, the ' format of D works without Evaluate.