# Can I use D[] inside of Plot[]?

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I wanted to make a plot like this:

`Plot[-BesselJ[1, z]*Evaluate[D[BesselJ[1, z], {z, 2}]], {z, 0, 5}]`

but I got an error. However, when I tried this:

`Plot[Evaluate[-BesselJ[1, z]*D[BesselJ[1, z], {z, 2}]], {z, 0, 5}]`

it worked. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1301) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35355)?

Comment: [Evaluate >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) : _"Evaluate only overrides HoldFirst etc. attributes **when it appears directly as the head of the function argument that would otherwise be held**"_