# How to plot $\left|y(t)\right|'$ where $y(t)$ is the output from NDSolveValue

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a complex valued ODE.

```
 ysol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == I Sin[y[x] Cos[x y[x]]], y[0] == .5}, y, {x, 0, 30}];
 Plot[Abs[ysol[x]], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The function $\left|y(t)\right|$ is plotted below:

[image]

I want to calculate the derivative of this function i.e., $\left|y(t)\right|'$. How can that be done? I tried the following but it does not work this way.

```
Plot[D[Abs[ysol[x]],x], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: `Abs[z]` is not a differentiable function of the (complex) variable `z`.  Since `ysol[x]` appears to be positive, why not use `D[ysol[x], x]`?  Alternatively, use `RealAbs[..]` instead of `Abs[..]`.

Comment: Also, see [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35355/plot-dsinx-and-evaluate) and its duplicate for why you should use `Evaluate` in `Plot[Evaluate[D[...]],...]` -- Alternatively, use prime: `Plot[ysol'[x], {x, 0, 30},...]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 ysol[x] is a complex quantity here. The graph that is plotted above, I just want to differentiate it. Is it just because it is complex that calculating its derivative is not possible?

Comment: Sorry about that, I guess it's getting late here and I didn't read carefully. Maybe this?: `Plot[Re[ysol[x] Conjugate[ysol'[x]]]/Abs[ysol[x]], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way to do accurate numerical differentiation on `Abs[y[x]]`:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
Plot[
 Evaluate@{
   Abs @ ysol[x]
   ND[Abs @ ysol[\[FormalX]], \[FormalX], x]
 },
 {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a more general approach that can be used in more complicated situations. The idea is to re-interpolate the desired functions

```
xmesh = ysol["Coordinates"][[1]];
asol = Interpolation[Table[{xi, Abs[ysol[xi]]}, {xi, xmesh}]];
```

Now you can easily plot the function and its derivative

```
Plot[{asol[x], asol'[x]}, {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let `u[x]+I*v[x]` be `ysol[x]`, so `Abs[ysol[x]` can be write as `Sqrt[u[x]^2 + v[x]^2]`, we can difference `Sqrt[u[x]^2 + v[x]^2]` and then use replace:

```
rule={u[x] -> Re[ysol[x]], v[x] -> Im[ysol[x]], u'[x] -> Re[ysol'[x]], 
v'[x] -> Im[ysol'[x]]}
```

```
Plot[D[Sqrt[u[x]^2 + v[x]^2], x] /. {u[x] -> Re[ysol[x]], 
    v[x] -> Im[ysol[x]], u'[x] -> Re[ysol'[x]], 
    v'[x] -> Im[ysol'[x]]} // Evaluate, {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]